# Fluent NHibernate com multiplas tabelas

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou usando o `Fluent NHibernate` para auxiliar do `ORM` (substituindo os arquivos .hbm feitos de forma manual) com uma única classe:

**Classe Usuário:**

```
public class Usuario
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }
    public virtual char Status { get; set; }

}
```

**Mapeamento da Classe:**

```
public class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Nome);
        Map(c => c.Login);
        Map(c => c.Senha);
        Map(c => c.Status);
        Table("usuarios");
    }
}
```

**Adição do mapeamento ao `Fluent NHibernate`**

```
var configMap = Fluently.Configure().Database(configDB).Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Mapeamento.UsuarioMap>());
```

> **Pergunta:** Agora necessito adicionar uma outra classe (Endereco, a instancia de Usuario terá uma propriedade Endereco) e uma classe Fornecedor(que não é ligada a nenhuma outra) ao Mapeamento,
>   como ficaria este mapeamento ?

**Nova Classe Usuário:**

```
public class Usuario
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }
    public virtual char Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Endereco EnderecoResidencial { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Endereco:**

```
public class Endereco
{
    public virtual string Rua { get; set; }
    public virtual string Quadra { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lote { get; set; }
    public virtual string Bairro { get; set; }
    public virtual string CEP { get; set; }
    public virtual string Complemento { get; set; }
    public virtual string PontoReferencia { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe fornecedor:**

```
public class Fornecedor
{
    public virtual string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public virtual string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que sua tabela de `usuario` possua uma FK para a table de `endereco`, você teria algo assim:

```
public class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Nome);
        Map(c => c.Login);
        Map(c => c.Senha);
        Map(c => c.Status);
        References(c => c.EnderecoResidencial).Column("endereco_id");
        Table("usuarios");
    }
}
```

Sua classe `endereco` tem de ter um ID:

```
public class Endereco
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual char Rua { get; set; }
    public virtual char Quadra { get; set; }
    public virtual char Lote { get; set; }
    public virtual char Bairro { get; set; }
    public virtual char CEP { get; set; }
    public virtual char Complemento { get; set; }
    public virtual char PontoReferencia { get; set; }
}
```

E seu mapeamento de `endereco`:

```
public class EnderecoMap : ClassMap<Endereco>
{
    public EnderecoMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Rua);
        Map(c => c.Quadra);
        Map(c => c.Lote);
        Map(c => c.Bairro);
        Map(c => c.CEP);
        Map(c => c.Complemento);
        Map(c => c.PontoReferencia); 
        Table("enderecos");
    }
}
```

Aconselho a utilização do `LazyLoad()` no mapeamento da entidade `usuario`, afim de evitar que toda a vez que você fizer um select de um ou mais `usuario`, venha toda a entidade Endereco. Se quiser, edito a resposta com um exemplo de utilizacao do `LazyLoad()`.

EDIT:

Como o `Fornecedor` não possui relação com nenhuma classe, seria apenas "mais um" na assembly do `Mapeamento.UsuarioMap`:

```
public class FornecedorMap : ClassMap<Fornecedor>
{
    public FornecedorMap()
    {
        Map(c => c.CNPJ);
        Map(c => c.NomeFantasia);
        Map(c => c.RazaoSocial);
        Map(c => c.Descricao);
        Table("fornecedor");
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

EXEMPLO DE UTILIZAÇÃO COM `LazyLoad()`:
Em todos os mapeamentos que quiser usar `LazyLoad()`, basta adicioná-lo conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
public class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        Table("usuarios");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Nome);
        Map(c => c.Login);
        Map(c => c.Senha);
        Map(c => c.Status);
        References(c => c.EnderecoResidencial).Column("endereco_id");
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, quando você fizer uma query de uma lista de usuarios, por exemplo:

```
using (var session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())
{    
    var listaUsuarios = session.Query<Usuario>();
}
```

Você terá as `propriedades` de usuário preenchidos na query e SOMENTE a chave estrangeira da entidade `Endereco`. Caso você NECESSITE da entidade TODA, basta dar um `Fetch` na entidade:

```
using (var session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())
{    
     var listaUsuarios = session.Query<Usuario>().Fetch(x=>x.EnderecoResidencial);
}
```

Aí além das propriedades, você também terá a entidade toda que você está dando fetch.

Comment: MarllonNasser como ficaria: var configMap = Fluently.Configure().Database(configDB).Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Mapeamento.UsuarioMap>()); juntamente com a terceira e isolada classe Fornecedor ?

Comment: `Fornecedor` teria alguma relação com as outras classes? Se não tiver, é só mais uma classe para ser mapeada pelo Fluent.. Em outras palavras, não precisa fazer nada se essa classe estiver com o mapeamento na mesma assemby do `Mapeamento.UsuarioMap`

Comment: MarllonNasser criei os mapeamentos em arquivos diferentes

Comment: Editei a resposta, `Ricardo`, é isso?

Comment: MarllonNasser Seria mas queria ver como ficaria o: `var configMap = Fluently.Configure().Database(configDB).Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Mapeamento.UsuarioMap>());` com as tres classes (Endereço que tem relação com Usuario e Fornecedor que não tem relação com nenhuma)

Comment: Ahh.. não precisa modificar nada... o proprio fluent entende que ele vai olhar para todas as classes que derivem da classe `ClassMap` desse mesmo "projeto"...

Comment: OK MarllonNasser então porque tive de adicionar este UsuarioMap?

Comment: MarllonNasser também poderia inserir o exemplo com LazyLoad?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33379/discussion-between-ricardo-and-marllon-nasser).